# Close jquery lightbox after file download

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, lightbox

I have built a simple form which opens up in lightbox on click of some link. On form form submission I have scripted to download the file using following php script...

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');                
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="pdf/myFile.pdf"');               readfile('myFile.pdf');
```

Now after form submission , file starts downloading, but I want to close lightbox after finishing file download or after form submission.

Could anybody please guide regarding the same.

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by using **style="display:none;"** for that particular **div** OR also can refresh webpage by using **window.location.reload(true);** function.

but i think the batter way is you should change **div** style to **display:none**.

Thanks.